# How to get around the implicit vs explicit function type error?

Tags: agda, plfa

This is from [the last chapter](https://plfa.github.io/Lists/) of PLFA book.

```
import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as Eq
open Eq using (_≡_; refl; sym; trans; cong)
open import Data.Product using (_×_; ∃; ∃-syntax; Σ; Σ-syntax) renaming (_,_ to ⟨_,_⟩)

infix 0 _≃_
record _≃_ (A B : Set) : Set where
  field
    to   : A → B
    from : B → A
    from∘to : ∀ (x : A) → from (to x) ≡ x
    to∘from : ∀ (y : B) → to (from y) ≡ y
open _≃_

data List (A : Set) : Set where
  []  : List A
  _∷_ : A → List A → List A

infixr 5 _∷_

data All {A : Set} (P : A → Set) : List A → Set where
  []  : All P []
  _∷_ : ∀ {x : A} {xs : List A} → P x → All P xs → All P (x ∷ xs)

data Any {A : Set} (P : A → Set) : List A → Set where
  here  : ∀ {x : A} {xs : List A} → P x → Any P (x ∷ xs)
  there : ∀ {x : A} {xs : List A} → Any P xs → Any P (x ∷ xs)

infix 4 _∈_

_∈_ : ∀ {A : Set} (x : A) (xs : List A) → Set
x ∈ xs = Any (x ≡_) xs

All-∀ : ∀ {A : Set} {P : A → Set} {xs} → All P xs ≃ (∀ {x} → x ∈ xs → P x)
All-∀ {A} {P} =
  record { to = to'
         ; from = from'
         ; from∘to = from∘to'
         ; to∘from = to∘from'
         }
  where
    to' : ∀ {xs} → All P xs → (∀ {x} → x ∈ xs → P x)
    from' : ∀ {xs} → (∀ {x} → x ∈ xs → P x) → All P xs

    from∘to' : ∀ {xs : List A} → (x : All P xs) → from' (to' x) ≡ x
    to∘from' : ∀ {xs : List A} → (x∈xs→Px : ∀ {x} → x ∈ xs → P x) → to' (from' x∈xs→Px) ≡ x∈xs→Px
```

When I fill in the hole with `to (from x∈xs→Px) ≡ x∈xs→Px`, I get the following error.

```
_x_1668 (x∈xs→Px = x∈xs→Px) ∈ xs → P (_x_1668 (x∈xs→Px = x∈xs→Px))
!= {x : A} → x ∈ xs → P x because one is an implicit function type
and the other is an explicit function type
when checking that the expression to∘from has type
(y : {x : A} → x ∈ xs → P x) → to (from y) ≡ y
```

I am not sure what this means, but Agda can be iffy when implicit arguments get involved. The one thing I have not tried is replacing `{x}` with `(x)` in `∀ {x} → x ∈ xs → P x` because it is a part of the problem definition.

What should the type signature be here? Also is there an easier way of doing this than a `where` block for every function in the isomorphism? I dislike the heavy copying of the type signatures.

Comment: You could eta-expand the function and write e.g. `(\ pr -> to (from x∈xs→Px) pr) ≡ x∈xs→Px`.

Comment: Nope, I get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried eta-expanding on the other side too? I couldn't test my suggestion as your question is not self-contained.

Comment: I edited the example so it is self-contained. Could you please take a look at it again?

Comment: Got a [reply](https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/3837#issuecomment-498061654) on the Agda issues page.

Answer (score 2):

Even with what @gallais said on the Agda page it took me almost 3 hours to figure out how to do this. Here is what I'd recommend the type signature to be. I ran into a lot trouble with functional extensionality. The actual problem was trivial in comparison.

I think the way inference works for implicit arguments could definitely use some maintenance.

```
postulate
  extensionality : ∀ {A : Set} {B : A → Set} {f g : (x : A) → B x}
    → (∀ (x : A) → f x ≡ g x)
      -----------------------
    → f ≡ g

postulate
  extensionality_impl : ∀ {X : Set}{Y : X → Set}
                  → {f g : {x : X} → Y x}
                  → ((x : X) → f {x} ≡ g {x})
                  → (λ {x} → f {x}) ≡ g

All-∀ : ∀ {A : Set} {P : A → Set} {xs} → All P xs ≃ (∀ {x} → x ∈ xs → P x)
All-∀ {A} {P} =
  record { to = to
         ; from = from
         ; from∘to = from∘to
         ; to∘from = λ x'∈xs→Px → extensionality_impl λ x → extensionality λ x∈xs → to∘from x'∈xs→Px x∈xs
         }
  where
    to : ∀ {xs} → All P xs → (∀ {x} → x ∈ xs → P x)
    from : ∀ {xs} → (∀ {x} → x ∈ xs → P x) → All P xs
    from∘to : ∀ {xs : List A} → (x : All P xs) → from (to x) ≡ x
    to∘from : ∀ {xs : List A} (x∈xs→Px : ∀ {x} → x ∈ xs → P x) {x} (x∈xs : x ∈ xs) → to (from x∈xs→Px) x∈xs ≡ x∈xs→Px x∈xs
```

Answer (score 1):

I have explored some alternatives based on [Marko Grdinic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56423455/5082913) to make the code more readable and simpler.

First I have found a slightly simpler way to define extensionality for an implicit argument using extensionality from the library:

```
open import Axiom.Extensionality.Propositional using (ExtensionalityImplicit)
open Level using (0ℓ)
postulate
  extensionality-implicit-0ℓ : ExtensionalityImplicit 0ℓ 0ℓ
```

And an implicit version of `cong-app` seems to be also needed for this exercise:

```
cong-app-implicit : ∀ {A : Set} {B : A → Set} {f g : {x : A} → B x} →
  (λ {x} → f {x}) ≡ (λ {x} → g {x}) → {x : A} → f {x} ≡ g {x}
cong-app-implicit refl = refl
```