# Looking for explanation about implicit function type vs explicit function type

Tags: function, types, implicit, agda, explicit

Considering the following agda module signature:

```
module EqList {a ℓ} {A : Set a} {_≈_ : Rel A ℓ} (eq≈ : IsEquivalence _≈_) where
```

We can define the membership in a list, the list inclusion and the list equivalence:

```
_∈_ : REL A (List A) _
_∈_ x = Any (x ≈_)

_⊑_ : Rel (List A) _
_⊑_ = _⊆_ on flip _∈_

_≋_ : Rel (List A) _
_≋_ = _⊑_ -[ _×_ ]- flip _⊑_
```

We can then proceed to prove that this last relation is indeed an equivalence relation:

```
isEq≋ : IsEquivalence _≋_
isEq≋ = record {
  refl = id , id ;
  sym = swap ;
  trans = zip (λ f g → g ∘ f) λ f g → f ∘ g }
```

The proof of transitivity is what makes my question arise. The previous definition is accepted by Agda while the following is rejected:

```
trans = zip (flip _∘_) _∘_
```

The error is as follows:

```
({x : A} → Any (_≈_ x) i → Any (_≈_ x) j) !=
((x : A) → Any (_≈_ x) j) because one is an implicit function type
and the other is an explicit function type
when checking that the expression _∘_ has type
(x : j ⊑ k) (y : i ⊑ j) → i ⊑ k
```

While this error feels weird, because both proofs should be equivalent (replacing the expression `f` by the expression `λ x → f x` should always yield the same result) I can somewhat understand why it behaves this way : there is intern trouble as to how to instantiate the various implicit arguments of `_∘_`. But this explanation is only intuitive and not very conclusive, so my question is the following:

**Can someone explain in details why the typechecker succeeds in the first case and not in the second ?**

---

As a side note, here is the header of the module, in order for this example to be self contained:

```
open import Relation.Binary.Core
open import Data.List hiding (zip)
open import Data.List.Any
open import Relation.Unary using (_⊆_)
open import Function
open import Data.Product
```

---

As a second side note, I am aware that a similar question has already been answered:

[How to get around the implicit vs explicit function type error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56355523/how-to-get-around-the-implicit-vs-explicit-function-type-error)

But said answer does not contain any deep explanation about this surprising behavior.

Comment: It seems to me like it is indeed true that Agda could be doing a better job at this. For example, see https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/2099